# Редактирование окна в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

Привет. Хочу сделать окошко со своими контролами и тд. Начал с создания шапки окна, поставил WindowStyle на none и добавил прямоугольник на верхнюю часть окна. Написал для него код, который позволяет мне перетаскивать окно за него. Все бы хорошо, но над этим прямоугольником всегда весит белая полоса и я не знаю, как ее убрать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в Blend все выглядит вроде как нормально, никакой полосы нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, хотелось бы узнать:

1. Как убрать эту монобровь сверху
2. Как убрать этот черный прямоугольник с кнопками сверху
3. Плюс, интересно, как изменить окантовку вокруг формы с голубой на
   какую-нибудь другую или вообще убрать.

Код разметки:

```
    <Window x:Name="MainForm" x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStyle="None"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="343.639" Width="525" Background="White">
<Grid Background="White">
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF232385" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47.542" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517" MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown_1" MouseLeftButtonUp="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp_1" MouseMove="Rectangle_MouseMove_1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Это просто инструменты для отладки, при запуске приложения не из студии их не будет. Но можно отключить их и в VS. Опция называется "show runtime tools in application", можно отключить или в настройках VS или в окне "Live Visual Tree"

Comment: Про панельку понял, спасибо, но монобровь и контур еще не побеждены :D

Comment: Код разметки показывайте

Comment: Добавил код выше

Comment: Попробуйте к окну добавить `AllowsTransparency="True"`, а первым объектом сделайте `Border` (со своей окантовкой, можете тень добавить итд..), внутрь `Border`'а уже помещайте свою разметку (в данном случае `Grid`.

Comment: AllowsTransparency="True" помогло убрать эту полосу сверху, но теперь я не могу изменять длину и ширину окна. Можно это как-то добавить? Или самому писать через код?

Answer (score 1):

1. В настройках Visual Studio можно отключить эту панель, по этому пути:
   Debug->Options->General->Enable Debug tools for XAML
   (Хотя на этот вопрос уже отвечали и в гугле очень просто найти это)
2. Нужно у Window установить атрибут ResizeMode на NoResize (тогда этой штуки не будет, но менять размер окна будет статический/заданный изначально, что в целом и так ясно)
3. Через BorderBrush и BorderThickness можно сделать (если надо детали гугл в помощь)